# Dynamic Child Component in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I am building an app with a consistent design pattern for lists of elements. If I have an object of type A, I create `AComponent` which accepts `a` as an input, then create another component to iterate over a list of A's, `AListComponent`. Then if I have an object B, I need to do the same thing. It seems like I should be able to make an `ObjectListComponent` passing in the class of the object I want to iterate over, to keep my code DRY.

For example, given

**AComponent Controller**

```js
...

@Input
a: A;
...
```

**AComponent HTML**

```html
<div>{{ a.name }}</div>
```

**AListComponent Controller**

```js
...

@Input()
aList: A[];
...
```

**AListComponent HTML**

```html
<div *ngFor='let aObj of aList'>
    <app-a [a]='aObj'></app-a>
</div>
```

How can we abstract the `AListComponent` to an `ObjectListComponent`?

**ObjectListComponent Controller**

```js
...

@Input()
type: any;

@Input()
objects: <type>[]

objectComponent: any;

ngOnInit () {
  this.objectComponent = <get object component from type>
}
```

**ObjectListComponent HTML**

```html
<div *ngFor='let obj of objects'>
    <app-objectComponent [object]='obj'></app-objectComponent>
</div>
```

where the `ObjectListComponent` would be used as

```html
...

<app-object-list [type]='A' objects='aList'></app-object-list>
...
```

Comment: U need to provide more info. How much diff are the `AComponent` vs `BComponent` ? I mean, are they all similar (css, functions) ? what is the purpose of `this.objectComponent` , how are you planning to use it?   If the only diff is the `type` then create interface `ICanvasComponentInput` and define type as `obj: A | B` inside it. use it in `ObjectListComponent` `@Input` param. (Try to give more generic name to ObjectListComponent)

Comment: The idea is that `ObjectListComponent` should be able to iterate over an arbitrary list of models because the component representing the model is passed in through the `type` attribute. 

`this.objectComponent` would be the component representing the type of objects in the list of objects passed in through the `objects` attribute.

Comment: I think I got the question little bit. It would be really helpful for me if you can create a demo on stackblitz.com . I'll take it up from there

Comment: It says that the requested page cant be found

Comment: Sorry about that, I haven't used StackBlitz before, so still getting used to it. This should work: 
https://stackblitz.com/github/bicarlsen/temp

Comment: Hi Bicaren, would you mind letting me know your feedback or upvote , if it helped ? I put some time out to get this solution so waiting for some reply

Comment: Hey @ShashankVivek, sorry for the late reply, was travelling. That gives a really good starting point. I made some final modifications for what I wanted. https://github-cmb2ba-6zm2jc.stackblitz.io

Comment: New link for the app: https://stackblitz.com/edit/object-list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for providing a demo code, [Take a look at this demo code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-cmb2ba?file=src%2Fapp%2Fobject-list%2Fobject-list.component.ts)

The main logic is there in **object-list.components.ts**

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
     const component_obj = this.getComponentType(this.objects[0]);
      this.containers.map(
      (vcr: ViewContainerRef, index: number) => {
        const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(
          component_obj);
        const componentRef = vcr.createComponent(factory);
        componentRef.instance['data'] = this.objects[index];
        this.cd.detectChanges()
      }
    )
 }
```

Basically, I have done is:

1. **a.component.html** : To handle logic of object `interface A`
2. **b.component.html** : To handle logic of object of type `interface B`
3. You can switch between 2 object types in **home.component.html**

**Shows Component A**

```
<app-object-list [objects]='aList'></app-object-list>
```

**Shows Component B**

```
<app-object-list [objects]='bList'></app-object-list>
```

> You can improve the logic to check and determine the type. That part of the code can be improved

Comment: I noticed there is a slight error occurring in that one of the elements of the list does not appear.